# OpenIdConnect middleware keeps adding "profile" scope to the request

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc, openid-connect, identityserver4

I'm tying to figure out OAuth2.0, OIDC1.0 and IdentityServer4. I've setup a test MVC Core client with only "`openid`" scope requested. But somehow OpenIdConnnect middleware keeps adding "`profile`" scope to the requested scopes. Is "`profile`" a mandatory scope? Should I enable it? Or what am I doing wrong here? I'd appreciate any input.

**IdSrv resources:**

```
_identityResources = new List<IdentityResource>
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResource
                {
                    Name = "test_user",
                    UserClaims = new[] { "test_user.email" }
                }
            };

            _apiResources = new List<ApiResource>
            {
                new ApiResource
                {
                    Name = "test_api",
                    Scopes =
                    {
                        new Scope()
                        {
                            Name = "test_api.account.create",
                            UserClaims = new[] { "test_api.account.create" }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
```

**IdSrv client config:**

```
new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "client.mvcx",
                    ClientName = "MVC Core Client",
                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,
                    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = false,

                    ClientSecrets =
                    {
                        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                    },

                    RedirectUris = { Common.Addresses.Client + "/signin-oidc" },
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { Common.Addresses.Client },
                    LogoutUri = Common.Addresses.Client + "/signout-oidc",

                    AllowedScopes =
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId
                    },
                    AllowOfflineAccess = false,
                    RequireConsent = false,

                    AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true

                },
```

**MVC Client:**

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationScheme = "cookies",
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)
            });

            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
            {
                AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
                SignInScheme = "cookies",

                Authority = Common.Addresses.IdSrv,
                RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

                ClientId = "client.mvcx",
                ClientSecret = "secret",

                ResponseType = "code id_token",
                Scope = { "openid" },

                SaveTokens = true,

                TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = IdentityModel.JwtClaimTypes.Name,
                    RoleClaimType = IdentityModel.JwtClaimTypes.Role,
                },
```

**IdSrv error:**

```
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint for /connect/authorize
fail: IdentityServer4.Validation.ScopeValidator[0]
      Invalid scope: profile
fail: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint[0]
      Request validation failed
info: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint[0]
      {
        "ClientId": "client.mvcx",
        "ClientName": "MVC Core Client",
        "RedirectUri": "http://localhost:32579/signin-oidc",
        "AllowedRedirectUris": [
          "http://localhost:32579/signin-oidc"
        ],
        "SubjectId": "anonymous",
        "ResponseType": "code id_token",
        "ResponseMode": "form_post",
        "GrantType": "hybrid",
        "RequestedScopes": "openid profile",
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `OpenIdConnectionOptions` automatically requests the `openid` and `profile` scopes (see [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/OpenIdConnectOptions.cs#L57)), with a private setter on the `Scope` property.

When you set scopes like you are, you are not setting a new list, but adding to the existing.

Clearing and then adding the scope works:

```
var options = new OpenIdConnectOptions();
options.Scope.Clear();
options.Scope.Add("openid");
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options);
```

Comment: or IOW - thank Microsoft for knowing what's best for you.

Comment: for updated source code link see lines 44/45 https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/OpenIdConnectOptions.cs

Comment: @leastprivilege typical MS